# JDBC get/setObject vs. get/setSpecificType

Tags: java, jdbc, types

JDBC [ResultSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) offers getObject, getInt, getString etc. methods, and [PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) has  analogous setters. Apart from type compile-time type safety, do the type specific getters/setters have any (dis)advantages, or is it OK to use getObject/setObject everywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no real technical (dis)advantages. They may only be functionally disadvantageous if you're doing typechecking/casting yourself afterwards.

I myself use `ResultSet#getObject()` only when the returned value is a primitive which is DB-defaulted to `NULL` and the declared value is a wrapper for the primitive. E.g. `Integer age`:

```
user.setAge(resultSet.getObject("age") != null ? resultSet.getInt("age") : null);
```

And I use `PreparedStatement#setObject()` practically all the time, in an utility method:

```
public static void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object... values) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
    }
}
```